# Monitoring a lot of small Spark clusters with Prometheus

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, prometheus

How can I use Prometheus (Which uses a 'pull' approach) to monitor my Spark clusters when I spin up a new cluster every time I need, which means I don't have one steady monitoring endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on how / where you spin up your clusters. When using Kubernetes, you can use [Kubernetes SD configurations](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config) to discover your targets or use the [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator) (see also [here](https://dzlab.github.io/bigdata/2020/07/03/spark3-monitoring-2/)).

If running on EMR you could use bootstrap actions to configure the [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) and [jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter). See [this](https://github.com/vinicelms/emr-monitoring-prometheus-grafana) for an example how to do so.

And alternatively, you could use the [Prometheus Pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/) together with a custom Spark sink ([example](https://github.com/banzaicloud/spark-metrics/blob/master/PrometheusSink.md)) for this use case.

Comment: I'm using Kubernetes. Are there any advantages to the alternative option? And can you elaborate on the Kubernetes SD Configurations? Because I heard on the autodiscovery option, Isn't it better?

Comment: Auto discovery is done by means of the SD (service discovery) configs. That's what I'd recommend if you are using Kubernetes. I haven't run Spark on Kubernetes though. But there's lots of examples online.

Comment: The pushgateway works as well of course, but distributing custom sinks on your cluster can be a hassle as well. As long as you can avoid this route, I'd rather avoid it.

Comment: And clusters that work for only half a minute can't be missed?

Comment: With the SD can I get information from the spark endpoint? On spark executors and other metrics that the spark driver supplies.

Comment: With very short lived clusters it might get tricky. I added another link above, hope that helps